# Tool to determine licenses for pom.xml dependencies

Tags: maven-2, licensing

I'm looking for a tool that given a maven pom.xml file tells me all the licenses that are used by the dependencies (and recursively their dependencies). Does such a thing exist?

Ideally it would tell me:

- For each dependency all licenses that apply
- A summary list of a different licenses referenced.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you have a look at the maven-dependency-plugin?

In the report it does not only list all the (transitive) dependencies, but also groups them by licenses, as you can see in its own [report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/dependencies.html).

Comment: The exact target seems to be:

project-info-reports:dependencies

Answer (score 25):

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependencies
```

then in target/site/dependencies.html you should see a pretty nice list of all your dependencies.

This is really taken from @Carsten, but I felt it was worth a full answer.