# maven report on licenses your project depends on

Tags: maven-2, licensing

I've got a big multi-module project, and I'd like to generate a report that shows all the licenses of all the things the project depends on.

I looked at tattletale, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.  And I can easily find a plugin that will squirt a license into the top of each source file, but this exact thing is defying my googling.

Comment: I had not seen Tattletale before - http://www.jboss.org/tattletale

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to determine licenses for pom.xml dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727091/tool-to-determine-licenses-for-pom-xml-dependencies)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [Maven Project Info Reports Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/) can be used to generate a *Project Dependencies* report that lists all dependencies and also **groups them by licenses**.

The [`project-info-reports:dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) goal can be used to generate an individual report but it should be used as a Maven report and is actually provided by default (see [Configuring Reports](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html)) when generating the site for the project in the `test` scope.

For an example, have a look at the [Licenses](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/dependencies.html#Licenses) of the *Project Dependencies* of the Maven Site Plugin.

Comment: Indeed -- thanks. mvn site has caused all kinds of problems so I haven't looked at its output for awhile; didn't realize I can run project-info-reports:dependencies stand-alone, and it seems to do exactly what I need. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

Also take a look at [License Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) . The [`license:add-third-party`](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/add-third-party-mojo.html) goal can be used to create a list of licenses associated with each dependency. The goal also provides functionality to allow you specify information about missing licenses.

Answer (score 11):

`mvn site` includes such an overview under dependencies, doesn't it?