# Dependency report for tycho based build

Tags: maven, dependency-management, tycho

Maven dependency reports can easily be created like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493507/maven-report-on-licenses-your-project-depends-on).

However, if I try to apply the solutions given there to a Tycho based build, I either get an empty report or even NullPointerExceptions during the build. Is there any way to create a (transitive) dependency report for Tycho based builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal `dependency:tree` of the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) should work for Tycho projects. IIRC, you need to call the plug-in together with at least the default lifecycle phase `package`, e.g. as `mvn clean package dependency:tree`.

Then you'll get something like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ org.example.bundle ---
[INFO] org.example.group:org.example.bundle:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.example.group:org.example.otherbundle:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.8.0.v20120430-1750:system
[INFO] +- p2.eclipse-plugin:org.eclipse.equinox.common:jar:3.6.100.v20120209-1951:system
```

Artifacts from p2 repositories can be recognized by the `system` scope; artifacts from the reactor by the `provided` scope. Note that the list of dependencies includes all transitive dependencies, but these are shown as flat list.