# list licenses of Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, licensing

I would like to maintain a simple list of all the licenses used by third party libraries for my dependencies in Maven.  I may be asking the question the wrong way and cannot find an appropriate plugin to do so.

I'm looking for something like [Grunt License](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-license), but for Java.

Comment: I think this thread will help you
[Pascal Thivent answer seems to be good][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493507/maven-report-on-licenses-your-project-depends-on

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: The following post answers this:

* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493507/maven-report-on-licenses-your-project-depends-on

Comment: I would take a deep look at the [license-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/)